# Unable to validate Brazil mobile number using ng-intl-tel-input

Tags: angularjs

I am using "ng-intl-tel-input" in my angularjs code to validate international phone numbers.

Everything works fine. But for Brazil mobile numbers, it doesn't accept some numbers.

For example: After area code, it accepts only 8 digits.

```
(+55)54 XXXX-XXXX - works fine
(+55)54 XXXXX-XXXX - not working
```

I need both the number has to work. (i,e) after area code it should accepts 9 digits.

Nothing to do with regex, as it is confusing.

Is any updated library for this?

Need someone help to resolve it.

Comment: I had same issue with indian new mobile numbers solved by using editing regular expression in utils.js file present.

Comment: thanks. but the regex is not understandable.

Comment: Hello, I've got the same issue here, did you make it?

Answer (score 0):

Google has an excellent library for handling international phone numbers

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: Thanks. But i need to do with the same library.